# How to calculate average of a timedelta column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, formatting, timedelta

I want to remove the '0 days' from my results, while being able to perform calculations with the formatted results

0   0 days 00:27:00
1   0 days 01:22:00
2   0 days 00:52:00
3   0 days 01:04:00
4   0 days 00:07:00
Name: Tempo Formatado, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

This is the result that I expected:

00:27:00
01:22:00
00:52:00
01:04:00
00:07:00

and being able to calculate the average, which in this case is 00:46

Comment: please provide code with your question

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to help without sample of your data, but let's assume your column is called 'time'. Then:

```
df['numeric_time'] = df['time'].values.astype(np.int64)
pd.to_timedelta(df['numeric_time'].mean())
```